# Scheduled task returns 0xFF, but works ok

Tags: command-line, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

The batch file converts mpg to avi and runs on a schedule.
Although the batch works ok from the schedule, Scheduled Task returns the 0xff message.
Running manually, it displays an exit code of 0.
I tried inserting 'end' - which gives a return of 0x0, but it only converts the first file and ignores the rest.

```
del /q /s staxrip_temp\* 
cd staxrip_temp
for /f "delims=" %%d in ('dir /s /b /ad ^| sort /r') do rd "%%d"
cd..
for %%f in (*.mpg) do echo %%f
for %%a in ("*.mpg") do call :go_now  "%%a"
 if %%a not==("*.mpg") goto eof
:go_now
echo processing %~n1.mpg
staxrip.exe -template:_myxvid "%~dpn1.mpg" -encode -exit
del /q "%~dpn1.mpg"
rem echo %ERRORLEVEL%
rem end
```

Resolved:
 Replaced **if %%a not==("*.mpg") goto eof**
with:
**if not exist %%a%% exit**

Answer (score 1):

Try adding an `exit 0` as the last statement in the batch file.

```
Quits the CMD.EXE program (command interpreter) or the current batch
script.

EXIT [/B] [exitCode]

  /B          specifies to exit the current batch script instead of
              CMD.EXE.  If executed from outside a batch script, it
              will quit CMD.EXE

  exitCode    specifies a numeric number.  if /B is specified, sets
              ERRORLEVEL that number.  If quitting CMD.EXE, sets the process
              exit code with that number.
```

---

Hmm ... I'm not sure of the exact semantics of the `call {:label}` command or how it "returns" - if your `:go_now` subroutine is returning normally (i.e., processing more than one file) when you don't put an `end` or `exit` there, then don't do that.

Probably need to change this

`if %%a not==("*.mpg") goto eof`

to

`if %%a not==("*.mpg") exit 0`

but I bet the reason why it's returning `0xFF` is because `goto eof` is a syntax error, you wanted to write `goto :EOF`.

Comment: Adding exit 0, only the first file is processed, then it exits.

Comment: if not exist %%a%% exit works, goto :EOF doesn't, neither does if %%a not==("*.mpg") exit 0